# How to use MyBatis to map MSSql Time to Java LocalTime type

Tags: mybatis, localtime

I am having DB chema with Time type:

```
[localTime]     [TIME],
```

I am having a POJO with field

```
LocalTime localTime;
```

Now, I am using mybatis to map checkout_time to LocalTime localTime using:

```
<result column="localTime" property="localTime"/>
```

I am getting following error:

> 28-06-2022 21:42:26.364 ERROR ]
> o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet].log[] -
> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path
> [] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.AbstractMethodError] with root cause
> java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
> at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet.getObject(JtdsResultSet.java:1806)
> at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getObject(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
> at org.apache.ibatis.type.LocalTimeTypeHandler.getNullableResult(LocalTimeTypeHandler.java:38)
> at org.apache.ibatis.type.LocalTimeTypeHandler.getNullableResult(LocalTimeTypeHandler.java:28)
> at org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler.getResult(BaseTypeHandler.java:85)
> at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createRowKeyForMappedProperties(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:1057)
> at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.createRowKey(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:1019)
> at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.applyNestedResultMappings(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:946)
> at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.getRowValue(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:434)
> at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValuesForNestedResultMap(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:909)
> at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:326)
> at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:301)
> at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:194)
> at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:65)
> at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:79)

I guess the mybatis is trying to access the localTime type handler but unable to return a null value or somthing. Can anyone help ?

Comment: You are using an old jTDS driver. Try the latest version of mssql-jdbc : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc

Comment: tried it: using mysql driver, getting same issue.

Comment: If it really is the 'same issue', there may still be the jTDS jar in the classpath because the stack trace contains `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsResultSet`. You need to remove the jTDS jar from the classpath. And, of course, you need to change the JDBC URL and driver class, at least.

Comment: I created a new timeTypeHandler, the current one was having no checks.

Comment: Well, if you have to use the old jTDS driver (whose latest release is 2013?) for some reason, you can use the [old LocalTimeTypeHandler implementation](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/a2ef920a5fc58256d57968c69423c033bf6779d3/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/type/LocalTimeTypeHandler.java). But, as I wrote, it is recommended to use mssql-jdbc which properly [supports](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/pull/749) `LocalTime` (and other `java.time` classes).